# Including a file on every page in a module

Tags: 7

I have a module that provides about two dozen pages (in a site with 1000s of pages). I have a file that contains a number of large functions. I want to include this file on every page used by my module. My options appear to be:

1. Call `module_load_include` in every page callback - seems a slight pain
2. Add the file option to every item in `hook_menu` (which would be fine as long as I don't want the page callbacks to go in a separate files from my .module file)
3. Wrap all the functions in a class, include the file using files[] in my .info file and then call the functions like `myclass::myfunction()` [which sorta seems a slight misuse of the class system as most functions are returning arrays of data unconnected to each other]
4. Load the file in `hook_init`, which means it would be loaded for every page in my site, not just the dozen specialist pages

It looks like 3 may be the best bet, but I'm just wondering if I'm missing something that allows me to include the file in one place just for my module pages without lots of duplicate calls to `module_load_include` and without using classes.

Comment: Wherever you'll load the page, you can always check the URL to make it conditional. So from the top fo my head I'd go for 4 and test URL chunks and `include_once` when you're on the correct path.

Answer (score 2):

If the file needs to be included on every page, the correct way is to use PHP's [`include`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) or [`require`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.require.php), I don't think the fact that this is in a Drupal site should really make any difference.

I've seen plenty of modules that literally put the following at the top of the module file:

```
require_once('module.inc');
require_once('test.inc');
```

If you really want to do it  a 'Drupal' way, you can use `module_load_include()` (which just wraps around `require_once` internally), directly at the top of the file instead of inside your page callback. This is what I tend to do normally.

```
module_load_include('inc', 'MYMODULE', 'MYMODULE.something');
```

Adding the file in `hook_init()` is perfectly fine too, I can't think of any justification to use one over the other, it would be down to personal preference.

Comment: I assume that sticking an include at the top of the module file would be run on every page, similar to hook_init(). I suspect the best bet is as Countzero says, and use hook_init and test the path. (I am also pretty sure I'm overthinking this, as I suspect any opcode cache worth it's salt means that including my 20k function file on irrelevant pages isn't much of a hit)

Comment: Yeah I think you might be over-optimising a bit there :) For the record, you can easily test `$_GET['q']` for the URL directly in the file too, so there's no need to implement `hook_init()`. I can't see any benefit in doing that, it adds an extra hit (however small) to the page load, and if you're worried about performance every little bit helps

Answer (score 0):

You could put the code into classes, either as static methods or full-on OOP.

Then you can use autoload to include those files when they are needed. Either using the files[] key in the *.info file, or using xautoload + PSR-0.

The benefit is that those class files will really only load when needed, and you don't need any manual include.